# Error creating bean with name: Injection of autowired dependencies failed, could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run my application (spring + hibernate) on a tomcat server but I am getting these errors. When I comment the property causing the errors, the next one triggers the same errors. 
I guess the properties are not recognized during initialization, I tried many solutions but none of them resolved the problem. Has anyone any idea to resolve this?

**Stacktrace**

```java
2019-06-17 15:07:19.706  INFO 12736 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5442 ms
2019-06-17 15:07:19.737  WARN 12736 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'san.prm.webservices.config.WebConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'maxAttachmentSize' in value "${maxAttachmentSize}"
2019-06-17 15:07:19.752  INFO 12736 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-17 15:07:19.771 ERROR 12736 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'san.prm.webservices.config.WebConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'maxAttachmentSize' in value "${maxAttachmentSize}"
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1692) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:465) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:415) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Import( { CoreConfig.class, PRMKeycloakRestClientConfiguration.class } )
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "san.prm.webservices.controller", "san.prm.webservices.authentication"})
public class WebConfig {

    @Value("${maxAttachmentSize}")
    private long maxAttachmentSize;

    @Bean
    public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
        return new ErrorPageFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ExceptionStatusService exceptionStatusService() {
        ExceptionStatusServiceImpl service = new ExceptionStatusServiceImpl();
        service.setDefaultStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        service.setExceptionStatus(getMappings());
        return service;
    }

    private Map<Class<? extends PRMException>, HttpStatus> getMappings() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public Module jacksonPageWithJsonViewModule() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("jackson-page-with-jsonview", Version.unknownVersion());
        module.addSerializer(Page.class, new PageSerializer());
        return module;
    }
```

**Initializer.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"san.prm.webservices.controller"})
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ WebConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class })
public class Initializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

**app.properties**

```
commonFilePath=${prm.app.commonfilepath}
maxAttachmentSize=${prm.app.maxattachmentsize}
documentFilePath=${prm.app.documentfilepath}
modeleDocumentFilePath=${prm.app.modeledocumentfilepath}
singleKey.keystore.path=${prm.app.singleKey.keystore.path}
genericPush.enabled=${prm.app.genericPush.enabled}
genericPush.keystore.path=${prm.app.genericPush.keystore.path}
genericPush.requester=${prm.app.genericPush.requester}
genericPush.stream=${prm.app.genericPush.stream}
genericPush.url=${prm.app.genericPush.url}
droitsFormulaires.enabled=false
clamav.host=${prm.app.clamav.host}
clamav.port=${prm.app.clamav.port}
```

Comment: why not application.properties instead of app.properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved it by adding this line in the pom

```xml
<filtering>true</filtering>
```

giving this

```xml
<build>
    <resources>     
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>                      
                <include>**/*.properties</include>                  
            </includes>
        </resource>            
    </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to rename your 'app.properties' file 'application.properties'? 
What is the path of this file ? It has to be under 'resources' directory if you don't want to manually configure its path.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your properties file resides in resources and you're copying it during compilation.

Also, the name needs to be application.properties or application-{profile}.properties. Read this for more info.

[Configuration | Spring Framework Docs](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

If not, you can use @PropertySource to specify properties file if you're not naming it as per convention or external configurations.

[PropertySource | Spring Framework Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

[Property Source Example | Mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I had app.properties and application.properties, I gathered these two files in application.properties and deleted the other but it does not change anything. The file is in "resources" directory and seems to be recognized by Intellij.

[resources directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x1oR.png)

I added this in the pom.xml

```xml
<build>
    <resources>     
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>                      
                <include>**/*.properties</include>                  
            </includes>
        </resource>            
    </resources>
</build>
```

and the following line in WebConfig but it is still the same.

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
```

The application I'm trying to run is a fork of an application that used exactly the same properties, and that runs well..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.
This issue resolved after I Invalidated cache from intelij.
Go to File -> Invalidate Cache -> restart intelij